# How to create a new branch from an existing branch for Bluemix project

Tags: git, ibm-cloud, continuous-delivery

I am trying to create a new branch from an existing branch named "develop". For this I am using the command,

```
git checkout -b release master
```

It shows that the branch is created ... But in the jazz hub UI, I don't see it. Are there any more commands to make this happen? Can someone help me real quick, please? ...Thanks

[image]

Comment: The command you used should work.  Is your Jazz Hub UI pointing to your remote repo or you local?  I'm not familiar with Jazz, is there some sort of refresh button/option you can click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to push your new branch to remote.

`git push origin release`